# I want to simulate Motor output WRT throttle

Tags: motors, automotive-engineering, electric-vehicles

I don't have any idea on how to get started. Can you mention required relations and concepts to get started.

Comment: This question requires clarification. Throttles control fluid flow which is appropriate to internal combustion engines, however, one of the tags for the questions is `electric-vehicles`. in your usage of the word 'throttle' are you asking about a fluid control valve in an internal combustion engine or the accelerator pedal?

Comment: accelerator pedal

Comment: Please _edit your question_ with any clarifications (i.e., the fact you mean the accelerator pedal of an electric vehicle).  As for actually modeling things -- there are too many different was to implement an accelerator pedal on an electric vehicle for any one model to be accurate.  I wouldn't trust the motor output not to vary with time after a step change from one setting to another, and while I would _hope_ it's not the case, I wouldn't even be surprised at some particularly low-quality example that has a non-monotonic relation between input and output.